# How do I iterate over my Set in a Batch Class?

Tags: apex, batch

I'm trying to iterate over a Set that is sent to my Batch Class, I am getting an error stating the following:

> Class FileCleanup must implement the method: void
>   Database.Batchable.execute(Database.BatchableContext,
>   List) (Line: 1, Column: 14)

Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong and how I should correct iterate over the set?

Here is my code

```
global class FileCleanup implements Database.Batchable<String>, Database.AllowsCallouts {

    //String query;
    public Set<String> cleanupList;

    global FileCleanup(Set<String> cleanupList) {
        this.cleanupList = cleanupList;
    }

    global Iterable<String> start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        return cleanupList;
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, Set<String> scope) {

        /// do some logic here
    }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Set` doesn't implement `Iterable`, but it *behaves* like an `Iterable` if you coerce it. Note, however, that the execute method will always only accept a `List` as the second parameter, because the set is implicitly converted to a list as part of the batchable serialization.

```
global class FileCleanup implements Database.Batchable<String>, Database.AllowsCallouts {
    global Set<String> cleanupList;

    global FileCleanup(Set<String> cleanupList) {
        this.cleanupList = cleanupList;
    }

    global Iterable<String> start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        // Cast here to force set to behave correctly
        return (Iterable<String>)cleanupList;
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, String[] scope) {
        // Scope is now a list, but it will be unique values only
        /// do some logic here
    }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to go is is this:

```
global Iterable<String> start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
    return new List<String>(cleanupList);
}
```

as `new List<String>` automatically implements `Iterable<String>`. That is not true for `new Set<String>` - see the unimplemented idea [Apex Code: Implement Iterable on Set](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kxLyAAI).

(But I can't explain why the error message you get is so obscure.)

Comment: Actually... It's more complicated than that idea lets on...

Comment: Oh, and FYI, the execute method was actually incorrect, hence the compiler error.

Comment: @sfdcfox Ah makes sense - I didn't notice that.